# Win32_Service: Use SetSecurityDescriptor() from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to set permissions for users on a Windows service from PowerShell. But WMI totally ignores my changes. What am I doing wrong?

```
$service = Get-WmiObject -EnableAllPrivileges Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "HubertService"}
$descriptor = $service.GetSecurityDescriptor()
$descriptor.Descriptor.Owner
```

So far this works. I now have a nice security descriptor. I can display the owner.

Now, if I change anything at all, for example the AccessMask of one of the ACEs, this works too:

```
$descriptor.Descriptor.DACL[0].AccessMask = 0
```

I can even write this modified descriptor to my Win32_Service object:

```
$service.InvokeMethod("SetSecurityDescriptor", $descriptor, $null)
```

However, before and after

```
$service.Put()
```

the modifications simply don't show up when I create a new $service variable and run GetSecurityDesciptor() on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimenting I found a solution.

```
# Get service object and its security descriptor
$service = Get-WmiObject -EnableAllPrivileges Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "HubertService"}
$sd = ($service.GetSecurityDescriptor()).Descriptor
$adacl = $sd.DACL
$adacl.Count # Shows current number of ACEs in the DACL

# Create new ACE for new user to add
$ace = ([WMIClass]"Win32_ACE").CreateInstance()
$trustee = ([WMIClass]"Win32_Trustee").CreateInstance()
$account = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("mydomain","hubert")
$sid = $account.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

# Fill in trustee and add trustee to ACE
$trustee.Domain = "mydomain"
$trustee.Name = "hubert"
$trustee.SIDString = $sid.Value # Don't need byte array
$ace.Trustee = $trustee

# Add ACE to DACL and replace DACL in security descriptor
$adacl += $ace
$sd.DACL = $adacl
$service.SetSecurityDescriptor($sd) # This appears to work just like that
```

The new ACE can also be removed again by replacing the DACL with one without the ACE to be removed.